# Unable to access member variable in onOptionsItemSelected in android activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-menu

I am trying to open a certain URL passed from previous activity with the browser. Click on the redirect icon on the right side, open the expected web page.

[image]

Here are my codes.

```java
public class DetailedProduct extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Menu menu;
    private String itemId;
    private String itemUrl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("DetailedProduct-LifeCycle","------------onCreate------------");
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detailed_product);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String itemId = intent.getStringExtra("itemId");
        String itemUrl = intent.getStringExtra("itemUrl");
        Log.d("itemUrl", itemUrl);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
//        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setTitle(itemId);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.v("Menu","----------menuCreate----------");
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.detail_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.v("Menu", "-----------menuSelect---------");
        if(itemUrl==null){
            Log.v("Menu", "---------Cannot acquire predefined itemUrl---------");
        }
        else{
            Log.d("itemUrlInner", itemUrl);
        }

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.redirect:

                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(this.itemUrl));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**The issue is that `itemUrl` is `null` in the scope of `onOptionsItemSelected`.**

I have assigned value to `itemUrl` in `onCreate`. However, as the log shows, it is `null`.

[image]

Hope for your help. Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onCreate` method you are using a local variable.

```
private String itemUrl;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    //String itemUrl = intent.getStringExtra("itemUrl");  //It is a different variable!
    itemUrl = intent.getStringExtra("itemUrl");
}
```

Comment: Stupid me! Wate my 2 hours! Thx

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning value to  `String itemUrl = intent.getStringExtra("itemUrl");` (local variable that ends its life as soon as its scope is hone) but reading it from `this.itemUrl` (field of your hosting entity). You need to write to and read from the same place.